# How to position Text within TextField (hint) in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, alignment, android-jetpack-compose

I have created a Text within a TextField to work as hint. I want to reduce the distance between the underbar and the hint text. How do I do that? I have tried using the following code:

```
      TextField(
                value = query.value,
                onValueChange = { newValue -> query.value = newValue },
                label = {
                    Text(
                        "Name as on Pan Card",
                        color = colorResource(id = R.color.fade_green),
                        modifier = Modifier.align(BottomCenter) //THIS LINE PRODUCES ERROR
                    )
                },
                textStyle = TextStyle(
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.fade_green),
                    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.poppins_regular)),
                    fontSize = with(LocalDensity.current){
                            dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._11ssp).toSp()},
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(
                        CenterHorizontally
                    )
                    .weight(0.3f),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(

                    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green),
                    focusedIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green)
                )
            )
```

I am getting the error `'fun Modifier.align(alignment : Alignment) : Modifier can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary'`

How do I solve this?

Comment: which version of compose are you using?

Comment: I'm using beta-04

Comment: You can't apply Modifier.align inside the label parameter, and in any case it will not reduce the distance between the underbar and the hint text.

Comment: What can I do to reduce the distance between underbar and hint text?

Comment: Currently I don't know a way to do it

Comment: Not yet.........

Comment: I was getting this same error when trying to put a piece of `Text()` center-end aligned to its neighboring start-aligned text (this is in a LazyColumn). So I wanted each of my list items to have two lines of text, left justified, with a single line of text right-justified and centered vertically on the end of the list item. I could use HorizontalAlignment for that `align()` function but not `CenterEnd`. I had to re-arrange my Rows and Columns and was finally able to use that `CenterEnd` alignment. It's not quite perfect but it's close now lol.

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced the same problem. I had this label and I wanted to align it to BottomCenter and couldn't.

Then I noticed that after adding the import it complains about needing a BoxScope:

[image: Alignment Error]

> Cannot access 'BoxScopeInstance': it is internal in 'androidx.compose.foundation.layout'

So what I did as a workaround is to wrap it in a Box with fillMaxSize():

```
label = {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(
            text = label,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
        )
    }
},
```

and this way I get the desired result:

[image: Label with text centred on the bottom]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`modifier = Modifier.align(BottomCenter)`

use

`modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)`